# Why does my Universal Windows .pfx file have a warning icon on it?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, raspberry-pi2, windows-10-universal, windows-10-iot-core, windowsiot

I created a Universal Windows app to be run on a Raspberry Pi 2 with Windows 10 IoT.  The project has a file called [myproject]_TemporaryKey.pfx and that file shows a warning icon.

1. Why is there a warning icon?
2. How do I get rid of the warning icon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does the file exists on disk?

Visual Studio usually draw this icon overlay to warn that the file referenced by the project file does not exists on disk.

This frequently happen when you get the project from a repo like GitHub. .pfx files are ignored by commits by default and so, can't be pulled.

To fix :

- create a new UWP projet
- copy the newly recreated .pfx file to your broken project folder
- rename the file as expected by your project